# How to write and read Android Realm?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I need to cache data in Realm in Android/Kotlin project.

When I write and then read – I get nothing. Previously I could write once, so I know that reading code works. But writes do nothing. Then I reset emulator and now I can't read anything. What I do wrong?

I tried to follow and [an official example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/java/quick-start-local/#std-label-java-client-quick-start-local) and the mistake slips away from me.

I have a data class:

```kotlin
open class DataItemExtra: RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: String? = null

    var strVal: String = ""
    var intVal: Int = 0
    var extra : String = "extra"

    constructor(id: String?, s: String, n: Int){
        this.id = id
        this.strVal = s
        this.intVal = n
    }

    constructor()
}
```

and a code in activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var realm: Realm

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val buttonSet = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonSet)
        val buttonGet = findViewById<Button>(R.id.buttonGet)
        val editTextString = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText)
        val editTextInt = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editNum)
        val textRes = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textRes)

        Realm.init(this)

        val realmName  = "My Project"
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .name(realmName)
            .build()

        this.realm =  Realm.getInstance(config)


        buttonSet.setOnClickListener{
            val strVal = editTextString.text.toString()
            val intVal = editTextInt.text.toString().toInt()


            Toast.makeText(this, "$strVal : $intVal",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            val di  = DataItemExtra("keyVal", strVal, intVal)

            Thread{
                this.realm.executeTransaction { transactionRealm ->
                    transactionRealm.insertOrUpdate(di)
                }
            }
        }

        buttonGet.setOnClickListener{

            val tasks : RealmResults<DataItemExtra> = this.realm.where<DataItemExtra>().findAll()

            textRes.text = ""

            val r = tasks.toArray()
            val rSize = r.size
            if (rSize != 1) {
                textRes.text = "wrong items number $rSize"
            } else {
                val d = tasks[0]
                textRes.text = "${d?.id}, ${d?.strVal}, ${d?.intVal}, ${d?.extra}"
            }

            tasks.forEach { d ->
                Log.d("REALM-RES","${d.id}, ${d.strVal}, ${d.intVal}, ${d.extra}")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's some threading issues. I didn't figure out what it is yet, but the right way to write data is to run `executeTransactionAsync` instead of running separate thread:

```kotlin
realm.executeTransactionAsync { transactionRealm ->
    transactionRealm.insertOrUpdate(di)
}
```